# Why do my columns not contain class names of their respective properties in django_tables2?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

On my local install when I render a table using django_tables2, every entry has a class name specifying that entry's attribute/property name. For example, the column containing that entry's product name will have the class "product_name" on both it's `<th>` and `<td>` elements. However, this does not happen in production.

None of the settings have been altered when transferring my local code to the server. Is this something I should explicitly specify in some setting somewhere? If so, where?

**edit**

An example of my code:

```
def brandWorkSheet(request, brandId):
    data = Product.objects.filter(brand__id=brandId)

    table = BrandProductTable(data)
    RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(table)

    context_dict = {
        'brand': Brand.objects.get(id=brandId),
        'products': table
    }
    return render(request, 'brand-worksheet.html', context=context_dict)
```

Comment: More people will be able to help you if you provide a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @thebjorn I am not doing anything differently from the quickstart examples on the documentations website though.. I will update the question but not sure how much that will help

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a different version of django-tables2 in production compared to development. I suggest to always pin version numbers to avoid having surprises like this.

The issue is we stopped adding the field/column names by default (as of django-tables2==2.0.0), because it often causes name collisions. [This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/issues/626) is about the same question, and shows how to add them with current versions of django-tables2.